# how to adjust background images with caption

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-services, frontend

http://awdhesh.goebasket.com/smartiq2/!

in chrome browser i am getting extra padding at the bottom how to remove that one how

i tried with this css code

```
figure#caption {width:100%; float:left; padding:7px 0; background:#333; color:#fff; font-size:24px; position:relative; top:556px; text-align:center; font-weight:500;}
figure#caption strong {font-size:36px; font-weight:600; display:block;}
figure#caption strong b{color:#E74C3C;}
```

still i am unable to solve this issue

[image]

Comment: Padding with respect to what? I am not clear what exactly is the problem

Answer (score 2):

You are fixing the top value `top:556px;` which would vary in different browsers. You need to set `bottom:0` to the bottom div with absolute position.

```
.topfix {
  height: 100%;           /*add other styles*/
}
figure#caption {
   position: absolute;    /*add other styles*/
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add position relative in following class:(may be you have to adjust 'top' property of class 'figure#caption')

```
.topfix .navbar-default
 {
     background: none;
     border: none;
     position: relative;
}
```